# Wrong Location Showing in HERE API

Tags: api, geolocation, maps

I enter some address to the HERE API but in that the location is showing incorrectly

I added the address with the postal code of the city. But in some cases (20% - 30% of my enterings) showing the wrong location.This happened for specefic postal codes only.When I'm entering a psotal code between 2000 to 2500 it worked properly but when I'm entering 2750,20%-30% of time it's showing not the location of 2750 but the location of 2000.Other 70% - 80% it shows the correct location.